# First try on a etcd HA & k3s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, etcd, k3s

I tried to run my first cluster as I'm currently trying to learn so I can work in Cloud Engineering hopefully.

What I did :

I have 3 Cloud Servers ( Ubuntu 20.04), all in one Network,

I've successfully set up my ETCD Cluster ( cluster-health shows me all 3 Network IPs of the Servers, 1 leader 2 not leader)

now I've installed k3s on my first Server

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server \ --datastore-endpoint="https://15.0.0.2:2380,https://15.0.0.4:2380,https://15.0.0.3:2380"
```

I've done the same on the 2 other Servers the only difference is I added the token value to it and checked it beforehand in:

```
 cat /var/lib/rancher/k3s/server/token
```

now everything seems to have worked but when I tried to `kubectl get nodes` , it just shows me one node...

does anyone have any tips or answers for me?

Comment: Can you show us output of  kubectl cluster-info --context yourClusterName

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RELKIku i hope it helps